# How to add controls to a JavaScript timer

Tags: javascript

How to add a 'pause', 'resume', 'reset' and 'end' functions to the following JavaScript count-up timer?

```
var sec = 0;

function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Literally _anything_?

Comment: And people wonder why they get downvoted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/9cq5e/1/

Comment: Why are you guys so angry to OP? He is member for today of our community and probably doesn't know all our rules.

Comment: nope. I didn't try. I am new to Javascript. I got confused with this 'minimal' code.

Comment: @Gavin is it possible to save the previous time while pressing 'stop'? When i tried to save it through different variables, it is not working..

Comment: I got it...
http://jsfiddle.net/sg5By/9/

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to check SO until this morning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have pointer to `setInterval` function for that:

```
var sec = 0,
  timeoutHandler;

function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}

function pausePad() {
    clearTimeout( timeoutHandler );
}

function resumePad() {
    pausePad();
    runPad();
}

function resetPad() {
    sec = 0;
    resumePad();
}

function runPad() {
    timeoutHandler = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    }, 1000);
}
runPad();
```